# Multiplication of a function handle

Tags: matlab, function, handle

In the first M-file in Matlab you can find:

```
f_1 = @(x)(1-x);  
f_2 = @(x)(exp(5^2*3); 

z_1 = FEM(f_1 , N);
z_2 = FEM(f_2 , N);
...
```

And in the second M-file:

```
function z = FEM(f, N)
%M is a 10x10 matrix
%f is a 10x1 vector
b=(M*f); 
...
end
```

How can I get `b` to be calculated in the right way? 
At the first time the calculation should be

```
b=(M*f_1);
```

and the second time to get `z_2`

```
b=(M*f_2);
```

How is that possible?

Comment: What does `M*f_1` mean to you? Do you want to form the function `@(x) M*(1-x)`?

Comment: I would like to multiply the matrix M with the vector f_1, b is a 10x1 vector. (Later I will calculate z=A\b. And z is the result I'm looking for.)

Comment: `f_1` is not a vector, it's a function. You might want to assign some values to `x`.

Comment: x looks like this: x=[0:0.1:0.9]'; it is a vector. When you insert it in f_1, f_1 becomes a vector.

Comment: Right, then you have to write `M * f_1(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't get it wrong, you want to send as parameter element of `M` to `f_1` and `f_2` functions.

For example:

```
M = [1, 2, 3, ...; ...]
b = [f_1(1), f_1(2), f_1(3), ...; ... ]
```

If you want to do like above, you can do that like:

First M-file :

```
f_1 = @(x)(1-x);  
f_2 = @(x)(exp(5^2*3); 

z_1 = FEM(f_1 , N);
z_2 = FEM(f_2 , N);
...
```

Second M-file:

```
function z = FEM(f,N)
    for i=1:1:10
        for j=1:1:10
            b(i,j) = f(M(i,j))
        end
    end
end
```

If not like that, you inform me.

Comment: I just added the information "%f is a 10x1 vector". 
What I try to do is the following:
b is calculated two times. The first calculation has to be with f_1, the second with f_2. PS: The code in the first file must not be changed. I write the code in the second file and to test if it works well the first file must run.